# item name/Can Destroy not working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I tried to make shears called Iron Cutters and make it destroy iron_bars but it only gives the name. It doesn't make me destroy iron_bars in adventure mode.

```
/give @p shears{display:{Name:"\"Iron Cutters\":\"Iron\""},Candestroy:["minecraft:iron_bars"]}
```

I am on Java edition 1.13, can someone help me?

Comment: Are you sure `Candestroy` is correct?  I can't check what the tag name should be, but you do need to make sure it's exactly the same (including case) as what the game expects.

Comment: Candestroy is incorrect. Capitalize the "destroy" as to spell "CanDestroy".

Comment: @SpiceWeasel Can you add that as an answer, please? I tested it and the command works with this command `/give @p shears{display:{Name:"\"Iron Cutters\":\"Iron\""},CanDestroy:["minecraft:iron_bars"]}`, as you suggested

Answer (score 1):

"Candestroy" is incorrect. Capitalize the "destroy" as to spell "CanDestroy":

```
/give @p shears{display:{Name:"\"Iron Cutters\":\"Iron\""},CanDestroy:["minecraft:iron_bars"]}
```